# Documents not listing in appwrite

Tags: reactjs, react-native, appwrite

I have a react native app which uses appwrite for BE.
I have created database,collection and documents.
But when i run the FE query its showings as documents 0. why is that? am i missing anything?

```
const client = new Client();
client
.setEndpoint('endpoint')
.setProject('id');
const databases = new Databases(client);

let promise = databases.listDocuments(
"[databaseid]",
"[collectionid]",
[
    Query.equal('title')
]
```

);

```
promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: {"documents": [], "total": 0} this is the response i am getting

Comment: permission is also set to "Any"

Answer (score 0):

You've used `Query.equal()`, but haven't given any value to search for.

`Query.equal()` is called like so: `Query.equal("ATTRIBUTE", ["SEARCHTERM1", "SEARCHTERM2", ...])`.